# Does both assignment considered as Spread?

Tags: javascript, rest, operators, spread

I have the following object:

```
const restaurant = {
  openingHours: {
    thu: {
      open: 12,
      close: 22,
    },
    fri: {
      open: 11,
      close: 23,
    },
    saturday: {
      open: 0, // Open 24 hours
      close: 24,
    },
  }
};
```

and two pieces of code that achieve the same result but are written a little bit differently:

```
const { fri } = restaurant.openingHours;
const friday = { ...fri };
```

this above is **Spread** syntax for sure

```
const { fri: {...friday} } = restaurant.openingHours;
```

Is the second one is a **Rest** syntax? I'm not sure what is the order of the assignment (that includes also destructing)  in the code

Comment: @souravsatyam not really, only the second one is rest, the first one is spread.

Comment: The first one assigns `fri` as a reference to `restaurant.openingHours.fri` and `friday` as a copy of the same. The second one never assigns a variable `fri` but retrieves `restaurant.openingHours.fri` and creates a copy named `friday`

Comment: When you expand the object and spread the properties within `{}`, it's spread. When you collect the remaining properties to a variable, it's rest. Does that make sense?

Comment: Why not `const friday = { ...restaurant.openingHours.fri };`? It seems inconsistent to me, that you create an intermediate variable for nothing in the first example, just to copy it later, and specify one part as dot notation, and the other as destructuring. At least use either `const fri = restaurant.openingHours.fri;` or `const { openingHours: { fri } } = restaurant;`, but this in between thing...

Comment: @ASDFGerte, The two example: **'At least use either const fri = restaurant.openingHours.fri; or const { openingHours: { fri } } = restaurant;'**  Are they different from what i have written in the first example?.. Also my purpose in asking this question is to understand how does **const { fri: {...friday} } = restaurant.openingHours** exactly works

Comment: I know, that's why one is named `friday`, and the others `fri`, similar to your code. Imho, clean code-style is very beneficial in avoiding misunderstandings. Towards the latter, you just ["take the remaining, and put them into `friday`"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Rest_in_Object_Destructuring), but haven't specified anything else, so it takes everything.

Comment: @ASDFGerte but is there a big difference between : `const { fri } = restaurant.openingHours;` and `const { openingHours: { fri } } = restaurant;`?

Comment: Not that i'd know of. The latter is the destructuring way for the prior (or rather, moving all the way to destructuring, the prior is already half the way).

Answer (score 0):

```
const { fri: {...friday} } = restaurant.openingHours;
```

Here `...friday` is a **Rest** syntax because we are creating an object from an indefinite number of values.

According to [DigitalOcean documentaion](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-destructuring-rest-parameters-and-spread-syntax-in-javascript#:%7E:text=Destructuring%20is%20used%20to%20create,an%20indefinite%20number%20of%20values.)

> - Spread syntax is used to unpack iterables such as arrays, objects, and function calls.
> - Rest parameter syntax will create an array from an indefinite number of values.